# Round down integer to end in 0 or 5 in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have integer values in Fortran like these ones:

```
120343
120344
120345
119349
118350
118355
```

And I would like to round down them so the last digit is always a 0 or a 5. So the above numbers would become:

```
120343 > 120340
120344 > 120340
120345 > 120345
119349 > 119345
118350 > 118350
118355 > 118355
```

I can write an algorithm to fix this, but I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to implement this using existing Fortran 90 functions.

I am using gfortran (gcc8).

Comment: Could you show the algorithm you would use?  It's probably very similar to what most people would write using standard intrinsics (there's no single dedicated standard procedure for this operation).  For example, I can think of a simple one-liner, but whether it's more straightforward...

Comment: For some reason I thought there would be a specific function in Fortran to do this (I am new to Fortran and I am still figuring out how to implement basic things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your table of expected outputs it seems that you just want to round your numbers down to the nearest multiple of `n` = 5. In such a case you are fine with the formula

```
y = x - mod(x, n)
```

The only more straightforward way could be clearing least significant bits in case that `n` was a power of two.

Comment: Thanks, so simple. I was thinking in something unnecessarily complex.